# Turn off the numbering of equations in the whole file

Tags: equations, numbering

I am using preparing a presentation with `beamer` and I would like to have all the equations without the numbers associated to them. I know I can use

```
\begin{equation*}
```

or similar. However, since I am going to copy a bunch of equations from another file, is there a way to set by default in the whole file that I do not want the numbering?

Should I redefine `equation` to be `equation*`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you load the `mathtools` package and use its `\newtagform` and `\usetagform` macros to achieve your formatting objective. Specifically, you could (a) use `\newtagform` to define a "tag" form (aka equation number) called, say, `nonums` that renders equation numbers invisible, and (b) make use of this tag form via a `\usetagform{nonums}` directive.

To make equation numbers invisible throughout the document, run `\usetagform{nonums}` in the preamble. To revert to the default tag form, run `\usetagform{default}`.

Observe that this approach doesn't actually *suppress* equation numbers entirely -- it just makes the resulting numbers invisible. This is useful if you need to create cross-references to equations, since cross-references may still be created via the usual `\label`-`\ref` route.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{nonums}[\phantom]{}{} % see pp 9f. of the package's user guide
%% or: \makeatletter \newtagform{nonums}[\,\@gobble]{}{} \makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Equations with and without equation numbers}

\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\usetagform{nonums} % don't display "tag", i.e., equation number
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\usetagform{default} % back to default tag form
\begin{equation} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a quick workaround, you may want to turn off numbering of *non-referenced* equations. If you don't reference equations, it will do the job. One of the possible ways:

```latex
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
```